# MongoDB aggregation to unwind, match, group query combination

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

This is my JSON data format. There are several data by different _id and orders.type on 1, 2.

```
{
    "_id" : "20200112000400",
    "orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "20200112000403",
            "type" : 2,
            "price" : {
                "basic" : 2600,
                "additional" : 0
            },
            "state" : 15,
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "20200112000401",
            "title" : "ABC",
            "price" : {
                "original" : 4000,
                "sale" : 2000
            },
            "amount" : 1,
            "type" : 1,
            "state" : 15,
            "commission" : 11,
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "20200112000402",
            "title" : "ABC",
            "price" : {
                "original" : 11000,
                "sale" : 8000
            },
            "amount" : 1,
            "type" : 1,
            "state" : 15,
            "commission" : 11,
        }
    ],
    "state" : 4,
    "date" : ISODate("2020-01-12T01:54:15.897Z"),
}
```

I want to aggregate only "orders.type: 1, orders.state 15"
and I want to aggregate the number of orders by document _id , not orders._id

this is example result

```
{
    "_id" : "20200112000400",
    "orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "20200112000401",
            "title" : "ABC",
            "price" : {
                "original" : 4000,
                "sale" : 2000
            },
            "amount" : 1,
            "type" : 1,
            "state" : 15,
            "commission" : 11,
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "20200112000402",
            "title" : "ABC",
            "price" : {
                "original" : 11000,
                "sale" : 8000
            },
            "amount" : 1,
            "type" : 1,
            "state" : 15,
            "commission" : 11,
        }
    ],
    "state" : 4,
    "date" : ISODate("2020-01-12T01:54:15.897Z"),
},
{
    "_id" : "20200112111411",
    "orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "20200112000406",
            "title" : "ABC",
            "price" : {
                "original" : 4000,
                "sale" : 2000
            },
            "amount" : 1,
            "type" : 1,
            "state" : 15,
            "commission" : 11,
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "20200112000408",
            "title" : "ABC",
            "price" : {
                "original" : 11000,
                "sale" : 8000
            },
            "amount" : 1,
            "type" : 1,
            "state" : 15,
            "commission" : 11,
        }
    ],
    "state" : 4,
    "date" : ISODate("2020-01-12T01:54:15.897Z"),
}...
```

my query is this

```
db.getCollection("Purchases").aggregate(                        
    [                       
        {                       
            "$unwind" : {                       
                "path" : "$orders"                      
            }                       
        },                      
        {                       
            "$match" : {                        
                "orders.state" : 15.0,                      
                "orders.type" : 1.0                         
            }                       
        },                      
        {                       
            "$group" : {                        
                "_id" : "_id",                      
                "orders" : {                        
                    "$push" : "$orders"                     
                }                                           
            }                       
        }                       
    ]                       
);
```

This query returns on an order basis, but I want return on an purchases document, and not use unwind, orders.type : 2 data to be included
maybe possible, I want to conditional aggregate by orders size. 
for example, orders.type: 1 and document _id group, $match orders size 1, 2, 3, 4..

Comment: In your group stage, use `"_id" : "$_id"` to refer to the value of the field.

Comment: @Joe Thanks!! it works. 
Next, I want to count according to the size of the orders. Help me.

Comment: @박진웅 : Please do not ask multiple questions ! Also please do edit this question with all the scenarios list down & required o/p should be proper with all the scenarios applied as I can see your required o/p is totally out of order w.r.t. conditions you've mentioned !!